# C++ Linked Lists Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, nodes

I'm currently practicing some linked list assignments out of my book right now and I'm stuck compiling errors. The implementation file seems to be fine, however the header file is what is receiving the errors.

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class linkedList {
public:
    linkedList();
    linkedList(const linkedList& copy);
    ~linkedList();
    int getSize() const;
    void addEntry(T entry);
    bool deleteEntry(T entry);
    T getEntry(int input) const;
    linkedList operator=(const linkedList& right);
private:
    struct node {
        T data;
        node<T> *next;
    };
    node<T> *linkedList = NULL;
};


#include "linkedlist.cpp"

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

The errors I'm getting from my compiler is as follows:

```
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedlist.h(22) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedlist.h(20) : see reference to class template instantiation 'linkedList<T>::node' being compiled
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedlist.h(25) : see reference to class template instantiation 'linkedList<T>' being compiled
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedlist.h(22) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedlist.h(24) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedlist.h(24) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedList.h(24) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
        ..\linkedList\main.cpp(9) : see reference to class template instantiation 'linkedList<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::string
        ]
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedList.h(24) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedList.h(24) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
        ..\linkedList\main.cpp(10) : see reference to class template instantiation 'linkedList<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
c:\users\andym_000\documents\linkedlist\linkedList.h(24) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: You messed up your answer, now you have errors to code which is not there. You should expand the question instead of changing, post another one or use better place than SO for such help.

Comment: Possibly the problem is having `node *linkedList = NULL;`, that isn't legal in C++03. Omit the ` = NULL` thing, it is both unnecessary and illegal. Everything inside the class is constructed using default constructor (unless explicitely stated otherwise) and pointers are initialized to 0 (NULL).

Comment: you have to revert your question to it's original form. You can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29110973/revisions) so that you don't have to write it once again. If you don't fix it yourself, I will have to flag your question for moderator's attension.

Answer (score 0):

Um, `struct node {...}` isn't a template. Your errors are telling you that is has no idea what to do with `node<T>`.

Comment: Ahh I see, so what you're saying is I need to do

template <class T>
struct node { ... }

Comment: @andayn no, just `struct node { }`.  Nested classes in a class template automatically have `T` available.

Comment: Also, you can use a template within a template, but you do have to specify the new template. That is why node<T> would have thrown an error.

p.s. Changing your question like you did is going to make people misunderstand what the answers are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You use template notation with `node` class, which s not a template. `T` type is defined for whole `linkedList` - in definiition of `node` it is well defined type.

Note that `node` is defined inside `linkedList`, so it's qualified name will be `linkedList<T>::node` for `linkedList<T>` (i.e. each instantiation of `linkedList` has it's own `node` class).

So, just replace `node<T>` with `node` and that should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now after doing what you said to do, I only have three errors all saying constructor syntax is missing formal perimeters and the complier flags `node *linkedList;` inside the header file. Again I am at a loss on what to do.

Comment: @andayn SO is not a place for incremental debugging/support. Have you tried a chatroom?

Comment: @andayn Seems like the problem with particular `T` type. Your implementation needs it to implement both default (`T()`) and copy (`T(const T&)`) constructors, maybe provided `T` doesn't have them. This header alone doesn't produce any errors, and with proper implementation should work for most `T` types (like int).